# LEAD difference returning no negative value

Tags: sql

when I run the below, I was expecting some lead_difference values to be negative (2016 value < 1990 value). However I don't see that in the output. Could you pls help check if I missed anything? Thanks! Images of output

[image: 1]

[image: 2])

```
WITH a AS 
    (SELECT 
     region, 
     year, 
     SUM(forest_area_sqkm)/(SUM(total_area_sq_mi*2.59)) as percentage_forest_region
     FROM forestation2
     GROUP BY region, year) 
SELECT 
    region, 
    year, 
    percentage_forest_region,
    LEAD(percentage_forest_region) OVER (ORDER BY percentage_forest_region) - percentage_forest_region AS lead_difference
FROM a
WHERE year = '2016' OR year = '1990'
GROUP BY region, year, percentage_forest_region
ORDER BY region, year, percentage_forest_region DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leading by the percentage itself.  Presumably, you want the next value for the region based on the year.  That would be:

```
LEAD(percentage_forest_region) OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY year) - percentage_forest_region AS lead_difference
```

If you order by `percentage_forest_region` then all years and regions are combined and the next value is the next larger value.